# Angular2 routing with auxiliary outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a directory structured like this :

```
my-app
  |- src
    |- app
      |- private
        |- private.routing
      |- public
        |- public.routing
      app.routing
```

The `private.routing` file:

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: '', component: PrivateComponent, children: [
    { path: 'header', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'auxheader' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
  ]},
]);
```

The `app.routing` file:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'public', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'public', loadChildren: 'app/public/public.module#PublicModule' },
  { path: 'private', loadChildren: 'app/private/private.module#PrivateModule' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

From a component in the public directory, I try to navigate to a component in private after a successful authentication.

If I use `this.route.navigateByUrl('/private/dashboard');` it works, but using `this.route.navigateByUrl('/private/(dashboard//auxheader:header)');` failed with the following error`Cannot match any routes: 'private'`.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have to correct the URL,

```
this.route.navigateByUrl('/private/dashboard(auxheader:header)');
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It helps, the error is not the same `Cannot match any routes: 'header'` :)

Comment: can you add route where you have defined `private` path?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above: your path is wrong. Correct path to navigate should be:

```
/private/(auxheader:account)
```

Comment: It's not working, and what I want to do is navigate to dashboard and open a specific header.

Comment: Tham make the header a child of dashboard and navigate to `/private/dashboard/(auxheader:account)` - you will still stay in dashboard and the `HeaderComponent` will load into `auxheader` router outlet.